# Is saying  "JSP is HTML" a valid statement?

Tags: html, jsp

May sound a stupid statement but what surprised me it came from a well educated java professional. He argued:

> "JSP is HTML. Take a look at some decent jsp/servlet applications, and you will see that over 90% of your jsp file is html."

According to him since JSP pages contain a lot of HTML, so JSP is HTML. Then he continued

> "Decent jsp files are basic html expanded with some additional tags and el functions."

I am awed with these statements. Am I missing something?

Comment: This sounds too abstract. Can you illustrate with a couple of examples?

Comment: Have a look at this page, the whole conversation is there https://www.facebook.com/groups/2204806663/10150916248066664/?comment_id=10150916286521664&notif_t=group_comment_reply

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IMHO the generalization that "JSP is HTML" goes a bit too far.

I agree that, for the most part, JSP **files** will have a lot of html in them, but that is just because most http request that users make are for html files (which afterwards make their own requests for images, scripts, etc...).

If everyone started making requests for lisp files then most JSP files would be full of parenthesis, but the JSP technology in itself would remain the same.

And of course, most additional tags and el functions deal with HTML related stuff just because that is what most usefull to most developers.

In theory, whatever content types the browser sets in the accept header of the request, you should be able to respond with a JSP. Have a look at this example: http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/JSPAndAJAXExamples

Furthermore, one must realize the truth: at runtime, there is no JSP. Then you will see that it is not the JSP that writes HTML into the response, it is only Java.

This is because all JSPs are compiled (or ideally precompiled) into Java servlets that reverse what you have written in the JSP file and write that content into a stream. So in this respect a JSP is much more a piece of Java code than an HTML file...

As for the rest of the conversation going on about what is valid html, css and validation, it's just a big red herring.

My two cents.

Answer (score 2):

Well the file as a whole would not be HTML if it has PHP in, it would be a PHP script with HTML in it.  Once PHP process it and returns your response then it becomes HTML. (Obviously this is only the case if your PHP is returning HTML, it could be returning other things).

Im not sure I understand:

> not even all html is html a valid statement :)

If he is trying to say that not all HTML is valid HTML then he is correct, there are certain standards, certain tags, certain places you can use certain attributes all available in the HTML spec.

**EDIT after reading conversation:**

Ok, so I just read the conversation and what I said stands, he was saying all html is not valid html which is true.  Just because it has html tags in and some text doesn't mean its valid, you can check if its valid or not by going [here.](http://validator.w3.org/)

As for JSP etc not being valid html, that is correct but they do/can produce valid html.  a JSP/PHP/ASP page is not HTML but has/can have html in it.  When a request is made to the server the file is processed server side and returns in the http response your HTML, this again may or may not be valid HTML.

Furthermore what they tell you about HTML is correct, it is not in itself styling, it is a markup that tells the browser the structure of your document.  The browser has its own default styling for those particular elements, which you can override by implementing your own style in CSS.

Comment: Can you visit the link in the comment, you will be able to see the whole conversation there.

Comment: Please stop before you misunderstand me more. For one, by saying "JSP is HTML" is an invalid statement. I never said that a JSP/PHP/ASP page cannot have html. Secondly, I misunderstood the statement he explained it a lot latter, in the meantime I had already asked the question. Have a re-look at the question.

Comment: well id stick with my statements, whether it is you or him that agrees with them.  Doesn;t make a difference to me.  To me JSP is JSP, HTML is HTML, JSP produces HTML.  A significant majority of a JSP file can be made up of HTML markup, but to me this does not make it HTML in itself.  Once it is returned from the server with no JSP in it and it is plain HTML then you can say its a HTML page.

Comment: You first para was what I was looking for.